# Return a Nothing from while zipping

Tags: haskell

I'm zipping two lists using `-` as follows:

```
differences = zipWith (-) [5,6,7,8,9] [1,2,3,9,5]
```

Is it possible for `differences` to return a `Nothing` if one of the zipped items is negative? So I'd like the function to stop zipping and return `Nothing` when it hits the 4th item in the above example.

Edit: or how do I combine it with other functions to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: not by itself (it'll produce lists) - but you can combine it with other functions after

Comment: @Carsten, do you have an example?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Control.Monad.zipWithM` with a custom function doing the subtraction:

```
Prelude> let f x y = if x - y < 0 then Nothing else Just (x - y)
Prelude> import Control.Monad
Prelude Control.Monad> zipWithM f [5,6,7,8,9] [1,2,3,9,5]
Nothing
Prelude Control.Monad> zipWithM f [5,6,7,9,9] [1,2,3,9,5]
Just [4,4,4,0,4]
```

Comment: Nice! We can also use `let f x y = do guard (x - y < 0); return (x - y)`

Answer (score 2):

No need to put everything in zipWith. Haskell is lazy. Processing is done when list is evaluated.

```
differences = zipWith (-) [5,6,7,8,9] [1,2,3,9,5]
result | any (<0) differences = Nothing
       | otherwise = Just differences
```

Downside is that it is needed to evaluate whole list (untill condition), but that can not be avoided for requirement.